# Matplotlib animate data in a dataframe using FuncAnimation command in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, animation, matplotlib, python-xarray

I have data saved in a dataframe format (xarray, similar to Pandas), and I want it to be animated with pcolormesh.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = mytest.TMP_P0_L1_GLL0[i]
    ax1.pcolormesh(graph_data)

FuncAnimation(plt,animate,frames=100)
```

which doesn't work for some reason (there is no error but when I show fig it is not animating).

the way the data is laid out is that pcolormesh(mytest.TMP_P0_L1_GLL0[0]) will output a quadmesh, pcolormesh(mytest.TMP_P0_L1_GLL0[1]) will output a slightly different quadmesh...etc

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The signature of [`FuncAnimation`](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) is `FuncAnimation(fig, func, ...)`. Instead of the pyplot module you need to supply the figure to animate as first argument.

Further, you need to retain a reference to the animation class, `ani = FuncAnimation`. The following is a minimal example which works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

class test():
    TMP_P0_L1_GLL0 = [np.random.rand(5,5) for i in range(100)]

mytest = test()

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

def animate(i):
    graph_data = mytest.TMP_P0_L1_GLL0[i]
    ax1.pcolormesh(graph_data)

ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=100)

plt.show()
```